Postfix body_checks rejected a message — how can I find out which regexp was fired so I can remove that from the filter?
I have a body_checks file for postfix.
Unfortunately I rarely, but sometimes important mails are not received, because they are rejected by the body_checks, although there should be no match. Here is my body_checks file:
body_checks = pcre:/etc/postfix/body_checks
/xxlady/                               REJECT
/Aktfotos/                             REJECT
/betrogen/                             REJECT
/Anlageempfehlung/                     REJECT
/Porno/                                REJECT
/Pornovideo/                           REJECT
/Pfund/                                REJECT
/Wohltatigkeitsorganisation/           REJECT
/TronTee/                              REJECT
/90offbags/                            REJECT
/90offsunglasses/                      REJECT
/porn/                                 REJECT
/masturbieren/                         REJECT
/CPF\s057\s200\s664\s645/              REJECT
/CPF\s057\sxxx\sxxx\s645/              REJECT
/CPF\sO57\s2OO\s664\s645\./            REJECT
/Pu\$\$y/                              REJECT
/S#x/                                  REJECT
/Bitcoin-Wallet/                       REJECT
/track-paket-149/                      REJECT
/dhl-paket-track/                      REJECT
/asfona\.net/                          REJECT
/Ihr\sDHL-Team/                        REJECT
/Stockwell-London/                     REJECT
/Ray\sBan\sSunglasses\s2023\sStyle/    REJECT
/Bored\sApe/                           REJECT
/www\.85off-lv\.com/                   REJECT
/https:\/\/www\.85off-lv\.com/         REJECT
/Temps\sde\slecture/                   REJECT
/Spendencode/                          REJECT
/Viagra\sPrice/                        REJECT
/McAfeefor/                            REJECT
/McAfee/                               REJECT
/breercecet/                           REJECT
/WANCZYK/                              REJECT
/tinyurl/                              REJECT
/pessinastefano986/                    REJECT

The error message I receive is:
2024-04-08T10:33:45.983819+02:00 admin postfix/cleanup[1414013]: 37595320177: reject: body ImTpT+mI0EwcUpHvMLuJSvUWb7mYBmN1zQpOrN0o7X6ipZgpUna92TxyHzObekdTa8IwZkqmS9fO from o4.transactional.digitecgalaxus.ch[168.245.116.150]; from=<bounces+12270525-14cf-kontakt=rafaelbetz.de@em1070.notifications.galaxus.de> to=<kontakt@rafaelbetz.de> proto=ESMTP helo=<o4.transactional.digitecgalaxus.ch>: 5.7.1 message content rejected

I don't get what this crypted body ImTpT+mI0EwcUpHvMLuJSvUWb7mYBmN1zQpOrN0o7X6ipZgpUna92TxyHzObekdTa8IwZkqmS9fO is and why it gets rejected. But the mail was definitely legit.

This is some base64-encoded hash of something. Oh, by the way, what was your question?

Oh sorry, my question is how can I find out what exactly is being blocked so I can remove that from the filter and learn.

You can add unique custom reject codes to your regexps. Then, by seeing which code appeared in logs, you can find out what regexp matched.
Something like this:
/xxlady/    REJECT 5.7.1 message body rejected (dac1d073-3128-4f9f-8b49-d49ffaf27898)
/Aktfotos/  REJECT 5.7.1 message body rejected (b323abb6-52ff-4ba3-99b9-4bd3c73933ac)
...

I used a random UUID generator; you may use any approach, just make sure your random identifiers are unique (within the body checks) and aren't related to actual filter strings.
See man 5 header_checks for details (yes, body_checks are described on that manual page too).
